# how to handle users to update data only in page, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a problem while developing an application in codeigniter.

I have one table fruits:

```
fid  f_name   f_slug   color
--------------------------
1   apple     apple    red
2   orange    orange    orange
```

lets say user 1 is related to apple and user 2 is related to orange.

Now the problem is when user1 is updating both apple and orange by accessing url "account/edit/apple" or "account/edit/orange", while I want user 1 to update only apple not orange as orange is related to user2.

I am stuck here for 1 days, still no solution.

**edit method in account controller**

```
public function edit($slug)
{
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    }else{

        $data['user_id']    = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['username']   = $this->tank_auth->get_username();

        $usern = $data['username'];

        $data['fruits'] =  $this->account_model->get_fruit($slug);

        $data['activeTab'] = "";
        $data['title'] = "Edit fruit details";

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/navbar', $data);
        $this->load->view('account/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

**update method**

```
function update()
{   
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else{
        $data = array(

            'f_name' => $this->input->post('Name'),
            'f_color' => $this->input->post('Color'),
            'slug' => $this->input->post('slug'),
        );

        $this->load->model('account_model'); 
        if($this->account_model->update($data))
        {
            echo "successful";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "unsuccess";
        }
    }
}
```

**account_model**

```
public function update($data)
{

    extract($data);
    $this->db->where(array('slug' => $data['slug']));
    $this->db->update('fruits', $data);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code  ??

Comment: I have added code. please check

Comment: so what you want to update i mean which column??

Comment: from where `$data['slug']` comes as i see in your controller you only define `f_name` and `f_color` in `data` array

Comment: I am changing the color of apple by only user 'a', but the problem is user 'b' can change it using visiting /edit/apple.

Comment: So I am trying to prevent user 'b'  to update

Comment: 'slug' is there in update method, which i forgot to add her

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `update` function you send the current user who is logged in as well

**NOTE:** Assuming you are storing the logged in `user's id` in `session`

```
function update()
{   
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else{
        $userId = $this->session->userdata('userId'); //Get the userId
        $data = array(

            'f_name' => $this->input->post('Name'),
            'f_color' => $this->input->post('Color'),

        );

        $this->load->model('account_model'); 
        if($this->account_model->update($data,$userId))
        {
            echo "successful";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "unsuccess";
        }
    }
}
```

Now **account_model**

```
public function update($data,$userId)
{

extract($data);
$this->db->where(array('slug' => $data['slug'],'id' => $userId)); //Note d userId condition too
$this->db->update('fruits', $data);
echo $this->db->last_query();
return true;
}
```

**NOTE:** Dont know from where the slug comes from. You have to check on that since you are sending only `f_name` and `f_color`